# Ожидание GIF анимации

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Есть картинка, при нажатии на неё она заменяется на GIF и выполняется всего один раз.
Как с помощью jQuery можно узнать, что GIF уже показалась?
То есть нужно сделать так:
Картинка PNG, нажимаем на неё, она меняется на GIF (это я сделал).
Далее картинка GIF показывает анимацию один раз (это заложено в самой картинке), после завершения анимации она опять заменяется на PNG.

Вот код:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".chets-img").click(function() {
        $(this).attr( "src", "/img/Chest-c.gif" );
    });
 });
```

Comment: Такие вещи лучше реализовать на flash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIF сам по себе никакими событиями не сигнализирует о завершении анимации.

Нужно заранее знать продолжительность анимации и отсчитывать её таймером. Насколько я знаю, пока нет достаточно надёжных и кроссбраузерных способов что-то делать с отдельными кадрами gif-анимации. Остаётся серверный вариант: отправлять gif на сервер, там его разбирать, узнавать продолжительность, выстраивать стрип из кадров – что угодно.

Мне тоже интересно, есть ли другие решения.

Answer (score 2):

Может быть, проще сделать setTimeout() с тайм-аутом, равным длительности анимации на функцию возвращения PNG в атрибут src?